# Briefcase optional package on Virtuoso

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtuoso

I've installed Virtuoso open source and some of its packages (including Briefcase) on a Ubuntu VM following this [guide](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSUbuntuNotes). Everything was OK, but after restarting Virtuoso server when I tried to access the Briefcase application it failed. The error is:

```
Error 07S01

SR180: Extra arguments to , takes only 0
```

Any solution?

Comment: You can find the solution reading the reference guide: http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/SIOCRefTutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which archive did you build from the source forge or github archive as I would 
recommend use of the github repository and the "develop/6" branch as this 
contains the latest fixes  from a few days ago:
 [branch](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSGitUsage)